# Как из строки получить число с десятичной дробью?

Tags: javascript

Есть строка, по типу, 350.023px, из нее мне нужно получить число 350.023, но если использовать метод parseInt(), то остается только 350. Как сделать, чтобы вывелось число с десятичной дробью?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для этого [.parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

```js
var str = '350.023px';
console.log(parseFloat(str));
```